# How to call Stored Procedure with join on multiple tables in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have to call a stored procedure which is selecting records from multiple tables.

I have tried the following code, but it's returning null for columns from other tables than the entity class.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> InvokeStoredProcedureAsync(string input = "")
{
    var storedProcedureName = "sp_BulkSelect";

    using (var db = new MyDbContext(_options))
    {
        var result = await db.Set<TEntity>().FromSql(storedProcedureName + " @inputIds", new SqlParameter("inputIds", input)).ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
SELECT 
    [MainTable].[Id],
    [Table1Id],
    [Table2Id],
    [MainTable].[Table1Code],
    [Table2].[Table2Code]
FROM
    [MainTable] [MainTable]
LEFT JOIN 
    [Table1] [Table1] ON [MainTable].Table1Id = [Table1].[Id]
LEFT JOIN 
    [Table2] [Table2] ON [MainTable].[Table2Id] = [Table2].[Id];
```

`MainTable` class:

```
[Table("MainTable")]
public class MainTable : FullAuditedEntity
{

    [ForeignKey("Table1Id")]
    public virtual Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
    public virtual int Table1Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Table2Id")]
    public virtual Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Table2Id { get; set; }      

}
```

So when I call this stored procedure, `Table1Code` and `Table2Code` are missing in the return value.

I tried to add the following code in `MainTable` class, but its also not working.

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual string Table2Code { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public virtual string Table1Code { get; set; }
```

Then I removed `[NotMapped]` from both the properties and added migration, in this case, its returning proper value. But It will add two columns in MainTable. **It's really a `BAD` design**.

So my question is how to select columns from multiple tables in the stored procedure in Entity Framework Core.

I'm using EF Core 2.0.

I think there has to be some way to call the stored procedure with using Entity and then map it to any class because select columns from multiple tables using join is a very basic requirement.

I tried the similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27807174/6527049), but its giving compilation error.

> 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no
>   extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Comment: "When I call this SP, it's returning `null` value for `Table1Code`" → Well, where's `Table1Code` defined?

Comment: "I tried to add the following code in MainArticle class, but its also not working." → How is `MainArticle` related to `MainTable`?

Comment: @aaron I have modified the question, please check

Comment: It was typing mistake

Comment: Where's `Table1Code` defined?

Comment: Initially, It's not defined in `MainTable`. But later I tried `[NotMapped] Table1Code`  and then `Table1Code` in `MainTable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlQuery into a \[NotMapped\] field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391619/sqlquery-into-a-notmapped-field)

Comment: Tried, But it's giving compilation error. 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core/46013305#46013305

Comment: It's not possible currently. Eventually in the next EF Core 2.1 release - see **Read-only view types in the model** in the [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap)

Comment: Then what’s workaround for this now? And when can I expect for core 2.1 release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete idea to get data from a stored procedure is as follows:

1. You need to add an entity that has the same properties as the procedures select query has.
2. Add the entity to your `DbContext` and Create a migration. Change the code in the `Up()` and `Down()` methods of the migration so that it creates the procedure in the database.
3. Now use the `FromSql()` method to get the data a normal entity data.

Here is some code that can guide you. Suppose you have these entities in your application domain:

1. Student
2. Parent
3. SchoolClass
4. Section
5. Enrollment

Migrations up method

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "StudentDetails");

        migrationBuilder.Sql(
            @"create proc GetStudentDetail
            @ssid int,
            @sectionId int = null
            as
            select Id, name, Gender, RollNumber, Status, Type,
            FatherName, FatherContact, SchoolClass, Section,
            SsId, SectionId, EnrollmentId
            from 
            (
                SELECT stu.Id, stu.name, stu.Gender, en.RollNumber, en.Status, en.Type,
                p.FatherName, p.FatherContact, sc.Name as SchoolClass, sec.Name as Section,
                ss.SessionId as SsId, sec.Id as SectionId, en.Id as EnrollmentId,
                en.EntryDate, row_number() over (partition by studentid order by en.entrydate desc) as rowno
                from SchoolSessions ss
                join SchoolClasses sc on ss.SessionId = sc.ssid
                join Sections sec on sc.Id = sec.ClassId
                join Enrollments en on sec.id = en.SectionId
                join Students stu on en.StudentId = stu.Id
                join parents p on stu.ParentId = p.Id 
                where ss.SessionId = @ssid 
            ) A
            where rowno = 1 and
            (SectionId = @sectionId or @sectionId is null)"
            );
    }
```

Migrations down method

```
protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

        migrationBuilder.Sql("drop proc GetStudentDetail");

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "StudentDetails",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                EnrollmentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                FatherContact = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                FatherName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Gender = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                RollNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                SchoolClass = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Section = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                SectionId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                SsId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Status = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Type = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_StudentDetails", x => x.Id);
            });
    }
```

The fake entity: All properties in this entity are coming from the above-said entities. You can call it a fake entity.

```
public class StudentDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    public StudentStatus Status { get; set; }
    public StudentType Type { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    public string FatherContact { get; set; }
    public string SchoolClass { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public int SsId { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Service layer to get data

```
public IEnumerable<StudentDetail> GetStudentDetails(int ssid)
    {
        var ssidParam = new SqlParameter("@ssid", ssid);
        var result = _appDbContext.StudentDetails.FromSql("exec GetStudentDetail @ssid", ssidParam).AsNoTracking().ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: It will create StudentDetails table in DB?

Comment: Yes. But in migration, I have dropped the table. Also, Note that it is just a workaround, not a proper solution. I read it on EF Git repository issues while working on my project. But I don't remember the link. Sorry about that.

Comment: What’s difference between these two Up and Down method?

Comment: When these Up and Down methods will be called?

Comment: Actually, I had two migration. First one creates the `StudentDetails` table in the database. Later using a new migration that I created for the Stored procedure, I dropped the table and created the stored procedure instead.

Comment: So if let’s say I have added the migration like this. And run update-database. So this procedure will be be created and this table will be dropped? I’m wondering that how will it work?

Comment: The `Up()` method will be called when you apply this migration. The `Down()` method is called when you un-apply the migration.

Comment: Do you think, you are answering my question?

Comment: This is working fine in my project. You should try this first, then only you will get it. I will update the link from the git repo very soon. Thanks

Comment: How to add Entity to DBContext in step 2?

Comment: `public DbSet<StudentDetails> StudentDetails {get; set;}` in your `DbContext` class.

Comment: You don't need to fiddle with the stored procedure or table in a Migration if you're using database-first.  Just add an entity matching the shape of the stored procedure output.  And 99.99% of the time if you have stored procedures, you should be using a database-first workflow.

Comment: @David,  For database-first approach, you are correct. But what about the code first approach, If I need to use a stored procedure which is complex enough as in the given code. It is not supported to run the stored procedure by now in EF-Core and I learned this workaround from the Git repository from some issue that I don't remember now.

Comment: "what about the code first approach"  Normally you would switch to a database-first workflow if you want to use stored procedures, views, triggers, ....  What you post _would_ work, it's just unusual to mix stored procedures and code-first.

Comment: I don't get it that why you are creating table in Down(). If we don't create it! will it still work?

Comment: I found, in part, the conceptual issue as to when the migration actiuallt runs on teh database is: (1) Add the table migration ... add-mgration sp1 (2) Edit the migration text under Migrations. (3) Then do  update-database     In editing the Up this added the Stored Procedure only and the Down deleted the Stored Procedure only.  :}

Comment: Still got a problem though in _appDbContext.StudentDetails FromSql is not an option. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidJones What's your EF Core version? It's possible that the EF Core has some changes related to this function.

Comment: Was EF V 6.5 updating to V7.0

Comment: OK Upgraded to 7.01 and can do .FromSql. Thx. But can only supply one parameter. Got around that with a "fudge".

Answer (score 2):

That's how it works in EF Core 2.1:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Query<YourModel>();
}
```

---

```
SqlParameter value1Input = new SqlParameter("@Param1", value1 ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
SqlParameter value2Input = new SqlParameter("@Param2", value2 ?? (object)DBNull.Value);

List<YourModel> result;
using (var db = new MyDbContext(_options))
{
    result = await db.Query<YourModel>().FromSql("STORED_PROCEDURE @Param1, @Param2", value1Input, value2Input).ToListAsync();
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1862#issuecomment-398353474)

Answer (score 2):

Below steps works in DB Design first approach EF core 3.1.0

1) Suppose SP(sp_BulkSelect) return  3 column by multiple tables(col1 int,col2 string,col3 string)

2) create fake Class  which will hold this Data, ***DataType should be same as per SP column***

```
  public Class1
      {
       public int col1 {get;set;}
       public string col2 {get;set;}
       public string col3 {get;set;}
      }
```

3) Used Modelbuilder to map call and  entity in MyDbContext class

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();
                entity.Property(e => e.col1);
                entity.Property(e => e.col2);
                entity.Property(e => e.col3);

            });
```

4) create fake table in MyDbContext class

```
  public virtual DbSet<Class1> Class_1 { get; set; }
```

5) Used MyDbContext class to call SP

```
 var Class1data = MyDbContext.Class_1.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE sp_BulkSelect {0}", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a View from select part of sql query --without where condition--.

2- Then generate your model from database and Entity Framework generates a model for your view.

3- Now you can execute your stored procedure using generated model from view

`dbContext.GeneratedView.FromSqlRaw("MyStoredProcedure {0}, {1} ", param1, param2)`