# Execute stored procedure with multiple joins and multiple entitles in returns columns

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework Core, and I have a stored procedure that contains multiple joins and retrieves columns from multiple tables.

How can I execute this stored procedure in EF Core 3.1?

I checked this link, and it says that I cannot do that
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

Can you help me to overcome these limitations?

[image]

Comment: There **are** the limitations of the EF Core at this present time - there's no way or trick to "overcome" these. If you can't live with these - then EF Core is the wrong tool for you - then you'd need to use "raw" ADO.NET or something like Dapper to handle this ...

Comment: What exact limitation are you hitting? And btw, you'd better look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) first rather than external sources. For instance, "The SQL query can't contain related data": does not mean it cannot contain JOINs. etc.

Comment: Maybe it will be your solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596681/12781348