# SQLite with spellfix1 extension used with entity framework core crash on second query

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

## Related stripped project

https://github.com/djon2003/mediarecognizer-spellfix1

The importing part has been removed and for sure I didn't included a database of 5 GB.

## Issue

I followed the instructions to compile the spellfix1 extension and it is working... well, not a second query.

I tested using an external software called "DB Browser for SQLite", loading my compiled extension and running the queries manually. No issue.

[This link gives you the exact line where it crashes.](https://github.com/djon2003/mediarecognizer-spellfix1/blob/069dea3495402a5ab853986fbc05038201c197ce/MediaRecognizer/MediaRecognizer.cs#L96)

As you can see there...

- first test: retrieving two different entities without SQLite extension => it works.
- second test: retrieving one entity with an another "using DB" using spellfix1 => it works
- third test: retrieving another entity in the same "using DB" using spellfix1 => it fails. (Commented)
- fourth test: (not included) retrieving one entity without spellfix1 after the one using spellfix1 in the same "using DB" => it fails.
- fifth test: retrieving two different entities in another "using DB" without SQLite extension => it works.
- sixth test: retrieving another entity in another "using DB" using spellfix1 => it fails.

The error I am getting each time is: `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'error during initialization: '.'`

I am not able to find anything about that. Next step would be to look directly in the extension code or SQLite code itself.

**EDIT**

More information: Modifying the SQLite extension by returning `SQLITE_OK_LOAD_PERMANENTLY` instead of `SQLITE_OK` on extension initialization fixes the bug. Though, this is only a patch.

Comment: I believe this is somehow related to connection pooling. If you disable this in your connection string having `$"Data Source={DbPath};Pooling=false"` things seem to go well.

Comment: Investigating why pooling might cause the issue (first idea is that it's trying to load extension twice, but not sure). Hope will come up with a useful answer.

Comment: @E.Shcherbo You are probably right, because I fixed it modifying the SQLite extension by returning `SQLITE_OK_LOAD_PERMANENTLY` instead of `SQLITE_OK` on extension initialization. This is only a patch though. I will try `Pooling=false` when I have a moment.

Comment: I'm writing an answer explaining details why the error happening with the current configuration, hope this will help you identify the correct configuration (I unfortunately know very little about sqlite so that can't advice properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much details how SQLite works and how EF should communicate to it properly, therefore I can't say if it is a bug or an expected behavior, but anyway the below is why the error occurs.

You see that exception because EF Core is trying to load the extension two or more times. According to the doc https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html#implementation_details (see 5. Persistent Loadable Extensions):

> The default behavior for a loadable extension is that it is unloaded from process memory when the database connection that originally invoked `sqlite3_load_extension()` closes.

But we know also that EF Core implements connection pooling meaning that with the same connection string the framework will try to use the connection from the pool and when you're done with a query it will return the connection to the pool. This means that it **doesn't unload** the extension when the query is finished just because the connection isn't closed.

And the bottom line is that only **physical connections are pooled**, but an object of the `SqliteConnection` type is some kind of logical connection, in fact it's an abstraction on the physical one.

What about logical connections (`SqliteConnection`). In fact a new instance of `SqliteConnection` is created with each `DbContext` instance you create and it's fully managed by EF Core. The EF Core seems to open/close this logical connection on each request to the database (**note** that opening/closing this connection are pretty lightweight operations, because is not a physical one and actual physical connection is taken from the pool). And EF Core sends requests to load requested extensions on each call to `Open`.

So let's get back to your code sample and see what's happening.

**MULTIPLE REQUESTS WITH THE SAME CONTEXT**

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
  var connection = (SqliteConnection)db.Database.GetDbConnection();
  connecton.EnableExtensions(true);
  conn.LoadExtension(@"SQLite Extensions\spellfix1.dll");

  db.Models.FromSqlRaw(SOME QUERY).ToList();
  db.Models.FromSqlRaw(SOMEQUERY).ToList(); // (1) will throw here
}
```

This throws in (1), because you have only one instance of `SqliteConnection` and two calls to the `Open` method (one for each request) which sends a request to load the extension. So the second call will attempt to load the extension for the second time and will throw.

**TWO REQUESTS EACH WITH ITS OWN CONTEXT**

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
  var connection = (SqliteConnection)db.Database.GetDbConnection();
  connecton.EnableExtensions(true);
  conn.LoadExtension(@"SQLite Extensions\spellfix1.dll");

  db.Models.FromSqlRaw(SOME QUERY).ToList();
}

using (var db = new Context())
{
  var connection = (SqliteConnection)db.Database.GetDbConnection();
  connecton.EnableExtensions(true);
  conn.LoadExtension(@"SQLite Extensions\spellfix1.dll");

  db.Models.FromSqlRaw(SOME QUERY).ToList(); // (1) throws here
}
```

This throws in `(1)` because the physical connection used to load the extensions in the first `using` is still opened which means that the extensions hasn't been unloaded before we load it again in `(1)`.

Comment: This is exactly the issue. Now, my current patch works, but I would like not to modify the extension as PERMANENT. I tried, disabling the connection lines in the second `using` and, in deed, no more issue. Though, because it is a pool of connections, if it creates a new one or use a connection that the extension has not been loaded, then it would crash.

Comment: @MasterDJon, I guess it would crash only if the original connection is closed. If a new physical connection is used and the old one isn't closed the extensions still should be in a process. So this approach will cause problems when the connection used to load the extensions is closed by some reason.

Comment: This looks like a bug for me and I think this question is a good candidate for the issue in the ef core github repository.

Comment: Do you mean with or without the modification of the extension to be PERMANENT?

Comment: I would add this would be a good candidate for both: EF Core & (SQLite or the extension spellfix1).

Comment: Oh you're right, seems like an extension loaded for the connection only by default, so that if it's not permanent and new connection is used this will cause problems

Comment: Just to be clear though, WITH the extension set as PERMENANT, no case will crash. But my goal would be to set it back as it were because I am sure this modification woudn't be accepted... and I would agree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242374/discussion-between-e-shcherbo-and-master-djon).

Comment: Hmm, I agree this might be a bug. Filed [dotnet/efcore#27529](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27529) to investigate.