# Using Include on FromRawSql query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

### Context

I have two classes: `MetaMovie` and `FuzzyMetaMovie`. The second one is a subclass of the first one. The parent class contains a foreign relation to a list of `MetaTitle`s called `Titles`.

`FuzzyMetaMovie` exists only to have an extra parameter that can be filled using a raw query.

`FuzzyMetaMovie` doesn't have a table linked to it because the result is gotten using a raw query on `MetaMovies` table and `spellfix1` SQLite extension.

### Problem

`db.MetaMovies.First()` gives me the first entry and the property `Titles` is filled.

`db.FuzzyMetaMovies.FromSqlRaw<FuzzyMetaMovie>(fuzzyQuery).First()` gives me the first entry, but the property `Titles`is **NOT** filled.

Added, for a commenter, the `fuzzyQuery` variable:

```
var fuzzyQuery = @"
SELECT '" + nameof(FuzzyMetaMovie) + @"' AS Discriminator, mm.*, fuzzyTitles.distance FROM MetaMovies AS mm,  
(
    SELECT mt.MetaMovieId, MIN(fuzzyWords.distance) AS Distance FROM MetaTitles AS mt, 
        (SELECT DISTINCT word, distance FROM MetaTitlesFuzzy WHERE word MATCH '" + title.Replace("'", "''") + @"' AND distance < 500) AS fuzzyWords
    WHERE mt.Title = fuzzyWords.word
    GROUP BY mt.MetaMovieId
) AS fuzzyTitles
WHERE mm.Id = fuzzyTitles.MetaMovieId";
```

### Attempts

I tried to use `Include`, but it gives me an exception.

I tried to use `Include` with casting to `MetaMovie`, but it gives me an exception.

I tried both above by adding `... INNER JOIN MetaTitles AS mt ON mt.MetaMovieId = fuzzyTitles.MetaMovieId` to my raw query.

### Not wanted solution if possible

Looping through all the results after calling `ToList` or else and filling by hand the property `Titles`.

Comment: Have you tried instead of `Include` just create needed class via `Select`? Also update question with `MetaMovie` definition.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I probably found my solution and all my requirements are met. Though, to be sure, I'll finish testing it today and give you news.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv As I said, I found my ideal solution. If you are interested to take a look. BTW, I hope you are doing well due to the "political" context.

Comment: Better post model as I mentioned, I will post my solution. I do not see any reason of those tricks when you can define extension method which returns `IQueryable<FuzzyMetaMovie>` without dancing with migrations.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Maybe you can look at those "related questions" about this project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229093/sqlite-not-existing-column-in-table-but-may-be-generated-added-from-some-queri/71753488#71753488 && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71244785/sqlite-with-spellfix1-extension-used-with-entity-framework-core-crash-on-second. In the latest one, there is a link to a striped version, but now outdated, but still relevant to this question.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Though, I am intrigued about your extension method solution.

Comment: Show at least `fuzzyQuery`. Everything too abstract.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Query added in the question.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I am still waiting about your extension method solution, if you still want to write one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that meets all my requirements:

Having a subclass that...:

- is not creating a new table
- is not included in the migration
- includes the foreign table of its parent

Previously the class `FuzzyMetaMovie`...

- had the attribute `[KeyLess]`
- was excluded from migration using `modelBuilder.Entity<FuzzyMetaMovie>().ToTable(nameof(FuzzyMetaMovie), t => t.ExcludeFromMigrations());` in the DBContent class

Now...

- I removed the `[KeyLess]` attribute
- I replaced the line to exclude from migration by `modelBuilder.Entity<FuzzyMetaMovie>().ToTable("MetaMovies");`
- I added a column in the table `MetaMovies` called `Discriminator` and filled it with `MetaMovie`
- When using the raw SQL, I ensure the first column is `'FuzzyMetaMovie' AS Discrimator` so I can still use `MetaMovies.*` afterward in case I add new columns.

Having all those changes, I see now the property `Titles` filled either using a "normal" query that transposes directly to `IQueryable<MetaMovie>` or using a raw query that transposes to `IQueryable<MetaMovie>` but containing `FuzzyMetaMovie` entries.